# jQuery sortable list into two columns?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I am looking to have a jquery list automatically sort into two equally sized columns on load.

Can't figure out how to get it to work - using the 'split-list' function doesn't work with the sortable plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/3swmnjjh/

Any ideas of how to get a list of five like this to split into two columns of two and three where it is autoupdated when items are dragged in between?

```
<ul id="sortable" class="split-list">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>   
</ul>
```

Comment: *" to get a list of five like this to split into two columns of two and three where it is autoupdated"* - so what happens to the 5th one..?  How should the new `HTML` look like? When/How does the list gets autoupdated..? What is *split-list* function..? Never heard of it. Can you give any reference..?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, You can use the [slice()](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method to retrieve a set of elements, wrap it in a new `<ul>` using [`wrapAll()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) and insert it after the last `<ul>` using [`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/), as shown below:

```js
 $(split);

 function split() {
   var listItems = document.querySelectorAll("ul li");
   for (var i = 2; i < listItems.length; i += 2) {
     $(listItems).slice(i, i + 2).insertAfter("ul:last").wrapAll($("<ul/>", {
       class: "sortable connectedSortable"
     }));
   }
   $(".sortable").sortable({
     connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
   }).disableSelection()
 }
```

```css
ul {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<ul class="sortable connectedSortable split-list">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Whenever the list gets updated, call the `split()` function again.